# Dividing one thread into two

Tags: discussion

I asked a question that ended up having two separate parts, and managed to obtain (with the subsequent help of Wolfram Technical Support) answers to both: [Combining pure functions containing compound expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188576/combining-pure-functions-containing-compound-expressions/188583?noredirect=1#comment491818_188583)

In the interests of helping this site be a readily-searchable resource, I think it makes sense to divide this question (and corresponding answers) into two parts, titled as follows:

(1) Keeping display ordering same as input ordering

(2) Obtaining non-null output from intermediate parts of a compound expression

That way someone searching for either the first or second topics can more directly find each.

Notes:
(1) is not quite a duplicate of [Changing the display ordering of orderless functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/169553/changing-the-display-ordering-of-orderless-functions/188564#188564) because the OP was looking for a function that would dictate the display order, while I was looking for a simpler approach that merely displayed the output in the same order that I typed it.  [So the function would just act to protect the display order, rather than specify it.]

And (2) is not a duplicate of [Compound Statements and returning earlier results in () parentheses](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180307/compound-statements-and-returning-earlier-results-in-parentheses/180312#180312) , since there the OP was looking to Print the results (which displays the results, but has Null content), while I want to actually get the results (such that I could assign them to variables).

Any objections to my doing that?

Comment: What you describe seems entirely reasonable to me.

Comment: Good enough for me.  Thanks!